# How to make an editable tree view in odoo

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo

This is my model:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class architect_page(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'

    architect_id = fields.Many2one('architect.form', string="Architect")
    architect_commission = fields.Float(string='Commission')
    architect_type = fields.Selection([('amount', 'AMOUNT'), ('percentage', 'PERCENTAGE')])
```

This is the architect.form

```
from odoo import models, fields, api


class architect(models.Model):
    _name = 'architect.form'
    _description = 'architect'

    prefix_id = fields.Selection(
        [('company', 'COMPANY'), ('architect', 'ARCH'), ('interior designer', 'ID'), ('others', 'OTHERS')],
        required=True)
    first_name = fields.Char(string="First Name", required=True)
    last_name = fields.Char(string="Last Name", required=True)
    address = fields.Char(string="Address", required=True)
    email = fields.Char(string="Email")
    mobile_no = fields.Char(string="Mobile No.")
    tel_no = fields.Char(string="Telephone No.")
```

This is the xml:

```
<odoo>
    <record id="architect_page_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">architect.page.view</field>
        <field name="model">sale.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//page[@name='order_lines']" position="after">
                <tree string="Architect Page"
                      editable="top">
                    <group>
                        <field name="architect_id" string="Architect"/>
                        <field name="architect_commission" string="Commission"/>
                        <field name="architect_type" string="Type"/>
                    </group>
                </tree>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

But the result is not the same as the order lines. I want to make it like this on my second page.

[image]

This is my second page pic:

[image]

I want it similar to the order lines which can add a product but in the architect page module, it can add another architect.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add one2many field on sales order object for "architect.form" object.. It seems currently you have added it as many2one that's why it does not look similar to order lines..

Regards,

Mustufa Rangwala (Probuse)